# Google App Engine: Using datastore with users who are not logged in

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am reading the Users Service to learn about the Users API before I deploy my app. I would like to have users try the app without logging in first. Is this possible? I need to store the input from a given user to Datastore and then fetch it. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't simultaneously crosspost here and in the groups; neither community can tell that there may already be good answers posted by the other. https://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/t/69ffd13840ab7451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users are not required to be logged in for you to use the datastore in your app.

If your demo stores data associated with a particular user, you will need to find a way to associate the 'demo' data with the right user.  Perhaps you can accomplish that using sessions.  If your using Python, you might look at [gae-utlitiies](http://gaeutilities.appspot.com/) or [gae-sessions](http://github.com/dound/gae-sessions).

Java has [built-in](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Enabling_Sessions) support for sessions.

Comment: I am using Python and I checked the links that you supplied. Thanks. At this point, I want to let any visitor to start using the app. The app has a form and it counts the frequency of words (this is just for learning). As you said, the visitor need not be logged in to use the app; but I noticed that the entries by non-logged in users remain on the site; I would like to erase them once the non-logged in user leaves the page. I suspect this can be done with Javascript. Can you point me in the right direction about how to update the page when the user leaves?

Comment: (I know how to erase the content, but not sure how to do it at end of session. Thanks again.

Comment: You might want to look at the `onbeforeunload` or `onunload` DOM events.  You may be able to use it to fire a 'cleanup' request to your app.  You will still need to implement some type of scheduled cleanup task on the server.